# How to look for in referenced document using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am working with MongoDB and I have a question:

```
Account: {
  _id: new ObjectId("<ID>"),
  name: "<NAME>"
}

User {
  _id: new ObjectId("<ID>"),
  email: "<EMAIL>",
  password: "<PASSWORD>",
  account: DBRef("accounts", ObjectId("<ID>"))
}
```

How can I look for users with and specific account name?

I tried:

```
db.users.find({"account.$name": "<NAME>"});
```

But it does not work.

How can I do it?
Is it a good practice?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Back into it" with `$lookup`.  First find the name you seek, then `$lookup` into the `users` collection.  Simplfying here:

```
var r = [
     { id: "A", name: "buzz"}
     ,{ id: "B", name: "NOTbuzz"}
     ];
db.acct.drop();
db.acct.insert(r);


var r2 = [
      { email: "buzz@foo.com", account: "A"}
      ,{ email: "notbuzz@foo.com", account: "B"}
     ];

db.users.drop();
db.users.insert(r2);

db.acct.aggregate([
{$match: {"name": "buzz"}}
,{$lookup: { from: "users", localField: "id", foreignField: "account", as: "X"}}
                ]);

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a12007bfee383d2d2e74651"),
  "id" : "A",
  "name" : "buzz",
  "X" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a12007bfee383d2d2e74653"),
        "email" : "buzz@foo.com",
        "account" : "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I appreciate!

Comment: Worth mentioning your use of the DBRef type was "on the right track" but it doesn't always do what you *think* it should do.   In general, DBRefs are just a legacy convenience object to pair a db name and _id.  MongoDB says "use manual refs instead."   All this is clear in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/